# Django, Celery: Retrieving a file generated asynchronously

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, pdf, celery

I have a page (`foo.com/process`) where you can generate reports for data. Sometimes the amount of data that needs to be generated is large, so it takes a while. Thus I made a Celery task to handle the PDF generation side of things. The reports are generated when clicking on a PDF image:

`<i data-processid="{{process.id}}" data-filename="{{process.pdf}}" class="fas fa-file-download getPdf"></i>`

When you click on that FA icon, an AJAX POST request is sent to the Django view:

```
$(".getPdf").on('click', function(event) {

    var thisId = $(this).data('processid');
    var filename = $(this).data('filename');

    $.post({
        url: "{% url 'process' %}", // Points to foo.com/process
        data: {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",
            id: thisId
        },
        success: function(data) {
            ... handle sucess
        },
        error: function(data) {
            ... handle error
        },
        traditional: true
    }).done();

    downloadPdf(filename);

    function downloadPdf(filename) {
        setTimeout(function() { window.location.href = filename; }, 10000);

    };
});
```

The AJAX function sends the request to the backend to start the Celery process to generate the PDF, and then immediately calls a `downloadPfd` function, which is simply a delayed function set to (what I thought was) the way to download a file through JavaScript. The timeout time is enough for the file to be generated.

I'm getting a file not found, even though the PDF file has been created and is located in the main project folder (I will move this later after I make sure it works, probably to the `MEDIA` folder in Django.

Now, I would probably be better off doing this through Django, which is another route I was trying.

On the POST part of my Django view, I have the following: (

```
class ProcessView(generic.DetailView):
    template_name = 'pages/process.html'

    def get(self, request):
        # GET stuff happens
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'process_form': process_form, 'process': process_list})

    def post(self, request):
            # Get the Process ID from the incoming request
            process_id = request.POST.get('id')

            # Get relevant objects and queries
            ... python and DB stuff ...

            # Fire off a Celery task to generate the PDF file asynchronously
            task = create_pdf.delay(sensor, range_period)

            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info, {"task_id": task.task_id })
```

That POST part all works. I click a button, it sends the AJAX POST which creates a Celery task, which generates a file. I can't seem to get the `task_id` on the front end, even though it is being generated.

The part I'm confused on is how to use the Celery `task.task_id` on the front end side to poll my Django view periodically to check whether the PDF file is done being generated, and then how to download said PDF. I have access to the filename, and task ID.

I'm trying to follow [this short tutorial](https://thoslin.github.io/async-download-with-celery/) but I can't quite make out the script portion of it (I'm not very good at JS), so I'm not really sure how to handle the "Check periodically if the file exists and if so, download it" part, since he seems to be using function based views and I use class based views in my project.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of missing pieces here, so I'll answer the first missing part:

1. To get the task_id from an ajax post your view should return a [`JsonResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects):

```
return JsonResponse({
    'task_id': task_id
})
```

2. Your javascript ajax success handler should unpack that task_id from the response that is typically handed back in the `success` handler.
3. Your javascript code should then regularly poll a separate django view that can retrieve the result of the celery task (which is presumably the filename) to get return the filename of the PDF that was generated.